# How to autowire generic classes by classtype?

Tags: java, spring

I have created a little framework that provides a set of classes:

```
class MyExecuter<T extends MyClass>
class MyService<T extends MyClass>
class MyPaginationService<T extends MyClass>
```

Anyone who uses the library so far must provide these classes as beans explicit:

```
@Bean
public MyExecuter<ImplClass> getExecuter() {
      return new MyExecuter<ImplClass>();
}
//repeat for all other classes


public class ImplClass extends MyClass
```

Most of the classes just contain the logical construct, and just need to know the type parameter of the implementation. The type parameter is the same for all classes.

Now, it would be even simpler if the user could just provide the type, eg `ImplClass.class`, and automatically all services noted above will get autowired and instantiated with that provided class. Without forcing the user to provide a `@Bean` explicit with that specific classtype.

Is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Why not have an abstract class that has all three bean methods that would then call each corresponding abstract create-methods. Autowiring would occur automatically because of `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`. How does that sound?

Comment: That's indeed an option.